# HTML/CSS Modal Dialog With Image (Sweetalert or Other)

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert

I'm making a website and have found the need to make modal dialogs. As I needed to include images and didn't like the look of the native `alert()` function, I settled on [sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/). So far, sweetalert works great but I need the ability to include images in the dialog (theoretically, sweetalert should allow this as it allows for arbitrary `HTML` content).

However, when I try to do this, the dialog becomes off center (vertically).

The code I use to create the sweetalert with image is:

```
var options = {
    title: 'Title',
    text: '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/">',
    html: true
};
swal(options);
```

**Brief JSFiddle demonstrating the problem**: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vj3nwgxb/)

So how can I use sweetalert to make a modal dialog that contains a custom image in it (not for the status icon, but actually in the dialog content)? If such a task is not possible using sweetalert, then is there a library I can use that makes good looking dialogs and supports what I'm trying to do? Worst case, I suppose I could write my own alert framework but I'm trying to avoid that.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

---

**Extra Info**: I assume this is because sweetalert calculates where the dialog should be, puts the dialog there, makes it visible, and then the image loads (making it appear off-center), but I could easily be wrong. This hypothesis is furthermore substantiated by the fact that, when using a constant image, the off-center phenonmenon only happens on the first load (every subsequent load the dialog is centered). I assume this is because the image is cached after the first load and thus the centering calculation is correct when sweetalert makes it on every subsequent load.

---

EDIT:
Here's a screenshot of what the off-vertically-centered dialog looks like for me on first load in JSFiddle:
[image: screenshot]

Note the lack of vertical centering. Screenshot taken on Chrome v45.

Comment: It is centered for me?

Comment: horizontal or vertical?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith it is not vertically centered for me (it is horizontally centered). I'll upload a screenshot of what it looks like for me on first load in a few minutes. It's as though when the image loads, it adds height to the dialog which makes it not vertically centered (for me anyway)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Added screenshot detailing what it looks like for me

Comment: It seems that it is adding margin to the top based of screen width http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/vj3nwgxb/1/ if you like I have a much easier example to use.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Thanks for the demo. Two questions that come to mind: 1) I notice you use 512px in your CSS `calc` expression (which I assume is the width of the dialog). On phones and such, the width of the dialog changes. How could this be reflected in the CSS? 2) For me, that renders the dialog near the top of the page (I wanted it to be vertically centered). Does it do the same for you? Maybe that's just because of JSFiddle?

Comment: Yeah, i was trying to set it vertically. I made a mistake it should have been 256px, i tried setting it to the center vertically however there is something in the javascript preventing it from working, I gave it a shot.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Alright thanks so much for trying. I'll glean what I can from your example.

Comment: I think someone else will have a solution shortly :)

Comment: This is probably an easier approach http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding dimensions to the image? if that is acceptable, that is working fine the first time for me.

Try this jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/santon/qunr0m7f/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#trigger-alert').click(function() {
    var options = {
        title: 'Title',
        text: '<img width="250" height="200" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/">',
        html: true
    };
    swal(options);
});
```

});

I would also suggest looking at [Jquery UI dialogs](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) as an alternative and [Toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) if you are looking to add notifications.

Adding another approach by preloading image.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/7/';

$('#trigger-alert').click(function() {
    swal({
        title: 'Title',
        text: "<img src='"+ myImage.src +"'/>",
        html: true
    });
});
```

});

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/santon/zfw6xetf/)

Comment: I'd rather not use dimensions if I could avoid it. However, that does appear to work for me as well so I'll gladly use dimensions if that is the only way to make it work. I'll wait to see if there any any alternative solutions first. Thanks!

Comment: @cryptopi: Added a solution with image preloading.

Comment: thanks for the multiple solutions! I'll probably wait to mark this as the correct answer tomorrow/day after to encourage a variety of answers (if someone else has one)